# Get Drupal View to Display Label from Numeric Custom Select Field

Tags: drupal, custom-fields, drupal-views, drupal-8, civicrm-entity

I have a custom field in Civi that is a numeric select field. The select field values are numeric but the associated labels are text. I have created a Drupal view that displays the select field but it only displays the numeric values. Is it possible to get the view to display the select field labels instead? In the view field formatter options it has "Default" and "Unformatted", but both show the numeric value.

I am using Civi 5.41.2 with Drupal 8.9.19.

Comment: hmm. feel we have hit this and fixed it though might have been on D9. will see if i can find that discussion

Comment: Thanks! Any help much appreciated!

Comment: sorry - had a quick search in our ticket system but not an easy search to filter on.

Comment: Are you using Dataprocessor extension? It has an "Option label" field type.

Comment: No, I am not using the Dataprocessor extension. Does that integrate with views in Drupal?